# Stop all transforms before applying a new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

So basically I have a floating object, which is done through the parallaxify js plugin. It adds translatex & y values to my object.

Now when I trigger an event, I want the object to fly out the screen. For this I am using a negative translate value and some transitions.

The problem here is, sometimes the object gets stuck while it's flying out of the window. Quite sure it is because there are positive and negative x values added the same time.

I tried setting transition to none before I trigger the event, not working. Same goes for the data-parallaxify-range, which specifies the range the object is moving on the screen. If set to 0, the object wont move. However, if I remove this attribute completely the object is still moving. I understand this aswell, because parallaxify is instantized on page load, so it needs a page refresh to work, but this wouldn't work either.

So, how can I solve this problem? I really want both effects to happen.

Thank you

/E:

HTML:

```
<img id="ufo" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); >/images/blank.gif" data-parallaxify-range="30"></img>
```

CSS:

```
 #ufo {  z-index: 2; width: 25%; height:     25%;background:url('../images/ufo.svg') bottom left no-repeat;position: absolute; top: 50%; left:10%; -webkit-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.490, 0.585, 0.505, 1); -webkit-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.490, 0.585, 0.505, 1.365);  -moz-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.490, 0.585, 0.505, 1.365); -o-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.490, 0.585, 0.505, 1.365); transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.490, 0.585, 0.505, 1.365); -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.490, 0.585, 0.505, 1); -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.490, 0.585, 0.505, 1.365); -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.490, 0.585, 0.505, 1.365); -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.490, 0.585, 0.505, 1.365); transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.490, 0.585, 0.505, 1.365);   }
```

Css-notransition:

```
.notransition {
-webkit-transition: none !important;
-moz-transition: none !important;
-o-transition: none !important;
-ms-transition: none !important;
transition: none !important;
}
```

jQuery, gets triggered on Scroll:

```
$('#ufo').addClass('notransition');
$('#ufo').removeClass('notransition');
$('#ufo').removeAttr("data-parallaxify-range");
$('#ufo').css({ 'transform' : 'translate(-'+ 150 +'%, 0px)'});
$('#ufo').attr("data-parallaxify-range", "30");
```

Comment: could you share the code you have so far?

Comment: Added in the question

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out! I found out I can disable parallaxify. I am using a one page scroll plugin, which has events for leaving the current page, with the index and the index of the next page.

Since the parallax is only on the first page, the "header", I am now using:

```
  onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
   if(index == 1 && nextIndex == 2){
   $('#background').parallaxify('destroy');
       $('#ufo').css({
         'transform' : 'translate(-'+ 150 +'%, 0px)'
       });
   } else if(index == 2 && nextIndex == 1){
    $('#ufo').css({
        '-webkit-transform' : 'translate('+ 0 +'%, 0px)'
      });
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#background').parallaxify({
                positionProperty: 'transform',
                responsive: true,
                motionType: 'natural',
                mouseMotionType: 'gaussian',
                motionAngleX: 80,
                motionAngleY: 80,
                alphaFilter: 0.5,
                adjustBasePosition: true,
                alphaPosition: 0.025,
         });
      }, 1000);
```

The duration for the page scrolling is 1 second, if I am going from page 2 to the first page, I activate the parallax with a timeout of 1 second. Without the timeout the flying object gets stuck while the page is scrolling.

Works like a charm.

Thank you for trying to help!